# Find the indexes of change points in sequences of contiguous numbers using Linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a List with specified values.It can contain any values. Assume which has following values for a test.

```
1,1,1,5,5,4,4,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3
```

I just need to find the successive number change locations as an output. for example in the above case the changes are `1->5 then 5->4, 4->1 and 1->3.` so the output list should return the location of changes as a result `4,6,8,11.`

I can iterate through the list and find the locations easily by comparison of successive numbers, **but I am curious about how to implement this in linq**.

Comment: To confirm, you want the 1-based offset of the first 'changed' value?

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way to do this, using the [Index overload of Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534869.aspx) to number the items, and then to Zip adjacent items (with a `Skip(1)`) and then to compare them:

```
var items = "1,1,1,5,5,4,4,1,1,1,3,3,3,3,3".Split(',');
var itemsIndexed = items
    .Select((n, idx) => (Value: n, Index: idx));
var result = itemsIndexed
    .Zip(itemsIndexed.Skip(1), (l, r) => (Left: l, Right: r))
    .Where(i => i.Left.Value != i.Right.Value)
    .Select(i => i.Right.Index + 1);
```

The +1 is because you seemingly want a 1 based indexing.

(I've used ValueTuples - substitute with `Tuple.Create` if you're on an older version of C#)

This is unlikely to be as performant as an imperative loop, of course!

Comment: You'd use `Left.Index` if you wanted the item before the change.

Answer (score 0):

As you want to do it using linq, so first you need to create another list of item and index, then check current item with previous item. if not equal then select it.

```
var arr = new int[] { 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };

       var output = arr.Select((num, i) => new { Num = num, Index = i })
                    .Where((item, index) => index != 0 && item.Num != arr[index-1])
                    .Select(z => z.Index+1);
```

[**.NET Fiddle**](https://dotnetfiddle.net/YryElQ)

Comment: I think it is better to add `Skip(1)` after first `Select` instead of condition: `index != 0`.

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov : I don't think so. because if you skip then I won't be able to compare `2nd` element with `1st`. as it `arr[index-1]` will throw `IndexOutOfRangeException`

Comment: Why not, you will start from `1 != arr[1 - 1]`?

Comment: @SlavaUtesinov : Correct me If I'm wrong. How does it will make better . You are also skipping `0th` index. only diff is I did it in another way.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution:

```
int[] nums = { 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
int[] changes = Enumerable.Range(1, nums.Length - 1).Where(i => nums[i - 1] != nums[i]).Select(i => i + 1).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this [soluion](https://dotnetfiddle.net/fCJQS2):

```
var list = new List<int> { 1, 1, 1, 5, 5, 4, 4, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3 };
var result = list.Select((v, i) => new { v, i }).Skip(1)
                 .Where(x => list[x.i - 1] != x.v).Select(x => x.i + 1).ToList();
```